# Display AND Capture stdout in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm struggling to write a rake task that can at the same time capture stdout and display the output to the screen. I have used many alternatives and nothing works. Here are some of them:

1. `stdout = sh('rake spec')`

   This is the closest I have ever got. The problem with this one is that the rake aborts. I think its because of failed specs.
2. `stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3('rake spec')`

   This captures the output but doesn't display the output at the same time.
3. `rake spec` enclosed in backticks

   This should work but it doesn't give me the whole output, I don't know why.

Please help, I want something which captures the output and at the same time displays the output as it normally does.

Comment: I don't know if it'll solve your problem, but this gem popped up on google and seems promising: https://github.com/jpastuszek/capture-output/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You could make a custom IO derived class that behaves like `tap` and allows you to display it as well as pass it through.

Comment: @Jordan I tried that gem and it is having the same problem of not showing full output.

Comment: This can be a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please explain why you want to do this. it might help a different solution altogether.

Comment: @gmuraleekrishna I am creating a rake task that would run `rspec spec` for a number of different ruby versions and at the end it would summarize how many tests failed for each ruby version. 

So I would capture the result of running `rspec spec` for each ruby version then I will use regular expression to print the number of failed example. That's the plan.